# Create DAX measure to get max sales from 2 specific years

Tags: powerpivot

I want to create a calculated measure that shows Max(Sales Year 2012, Sales Year 2013) for particular set of product. can we do this using the calculate function?

Prod    2010    2011    2012    2013
A   280 152 251 387
B   115 381 207 304
C   265 138 394 210
D   483 135 145 464
E   304 134 193 342

Answer (score 0):

Sure, that's one of the benefits of using *CALCULATE*!

Here is the formula for MAX sales in 2013:

```
CALCULATE([SalesSum],Sales_New[Year] = 2013)
```

- [SalesSum] represent just a sum of all sales and to make things a bit more organized, it's formula is very simple: SUM(Sales_New[Sales]).
- Sales_New[Year] is the name of the column that includes years (see below for more details).

For 2012, simply change the filter in the second argument:

```
CALCULATE([SalesSum],Sales_New[Year] = 2012)
```

One important thing though -- I needed to transform your source data so that I can do all calculation need. I named the table *Sales_new*. Attached screenshot should explain everything.

[image]